# Change the color of an element according to its value by CSS

Tags: css

Can CSS change the color of an element according to its value?

For example, if the numbers were positive, the color would be  green and if they were negative, it would be red.

If this can be done by CSS

```js
var number ;

setInterval(function(){ 
    number = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
  document.getElementById("in02").innerHTML = number-50
  
 
}, 1000);
```

```css
#in02{
color: red
}
```

```html
A = <a id="in02"></a>
```

, how should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a negative or positive class onto the element based on if the number generated is less than or greater than 0. The class then has the styling on it to color the text red or green.

Its always better to add a class that can be styled instead of adding the css to the element via the js. IMO.

```js
setInterval(function(){ 
    const el = document.getElementById("in02");
    
     const number = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)-50;
    number < 0 
      ? el.className="negative"
      : el.className="positive"
    
  document.getElementById("in02").innerHTML = number
  
 
}, 1000);
```

```css
#in02.negative{
  color: red
}

#in02.positive{
  color: green
}
```

```html
A = <a id="in02">0</a>
```

To answer your question - you CAN do this with CSS alone - its just not advisable. You could add the value to the element as a data-attribute instead of the innerHTML and thenuse CSS to display the data attribute as pseudo eleemnts - I do NOT recommend this - but it is an interesting exercise to see the power of the CSS selectors.

Note that the pseudo-elements are NOT included in the DOM and thereore are not read by screen readers are not accessible.

```js
setInterval(function(){ 
    const el = document.getElementById("in02");
    
    const number = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)-50;
    
  document.getElementById("in02").setAttribute('data-number', number)
  
}, 1000);
```

```css
#in02 {
  position: relative;
}

#in02::before {
  content: attr(data-number);
}


[data-number]::before {
 color: green
}

/* "Starts with" selector, meaning this would match numbers starting with '-', like "-3" */
[data-number^="-"]::before {
 color: red
}
```

```html
A = <a id="in02"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm use a `remove` and `add` class in javascript.
I'm added a css:

```
.in03{
color:blue !important
}
```

Then Javascript like this:

```
var number ;
var check ;

setInterval(function(){ 
number = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
check = document.getElementById("in02").innerHTML = number-50
if(check <= 0){
document.getElementById("in02").classList.add("in03");
} else {
document.getElementById("in02").classList.remove("in03");
}
}, 1000);
```

Will got output like this

```js
   

    var number;
    var check;
    setInterval(function(){ 
    number = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
    check = document.getElementById("in02").innerHTML = number-50
    if(check <= 0){
    document.getElementById("in02").classList.add("in03");
    } else {
    document.getElementById("in02").classList.remove("in03");
    }
 
}, 1000);
```

```css
#in02{
color: red
}

.in03{
color:blue !important
}
```

```html
A = <a id="in02"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) - 50;
  var color = number > 0 ? 'green' : 'red';
  in02.textContent = number;
  in02.style.color = color;
}, 1000);
```

```html
A = <a id="in02"></a>
```